# AddressSanitizer: invalid-pointer-pair from libc++ string __addr_in_range

Tags: c++, clang, clang++, address-sanitizer, libc++

The following simple program makes AddressSanitizer to report "invalid-pointer-pair" with latest master build of Clang (doesn't happen with the latest official release 15):

```cpp
#include <filesystem>
#include <iostream>

constexpr std::string_view str = "/usr";

const std::filesystem::path path{str};

int main() {
    std::cout << "Path: " << path << std::endl;
}
```

What happens:

```
$ clang++ -fsanitize=address,pointer-compare,pointer-subtract -g -O0 -std=c++20 repro-asan.cpp -stdlib=libc++ -o repro-asan
$ export ASAN_OPTIONS="detect_invalid_pointer_pairs=2"
$ ./repro-asan
=================================================================
==3183863==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: invalid-pointer-pair: 0x563a8315eb41 0x563a82764600
error: failed to decompress '.debug_aranges', zlib is not available
error: failed to decompress '.debug_info', zlib is not available
error: failed to decompress '.debug_abbrev', zlib is not available
error: failed to decompress '.debug_line', zlib is not available
error: failed to decompress '.debug_str', zlib is not available
error: failed to decompress '.debug_line_str', zlib is not available
error: failed to decompress '.debug_loclists', zlib is not available
error: failed to decompress '.debug_rnglists', zlib is not available
    #0 0x563a8274d818 in bool std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>::__addr_in_range[abi:v170000]<char const&>(char const&) const /home/me/dev/llvm/build/bin/../include/c++/v1/string:1979:23
    #1 0x563a8274d418 in std::__1::enable_if<__is_cpp17_forward_iterator<char const*>::value, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>&>::type std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>::append[abi:v170000]<char const*>(char const*, char const*) /home/me/dev/llvm/build/bin/../include/c++/v1/string:2805:14
    #2 0x563a8274d264 in std::__1::enable_if<__is_cpp17_forward_iterator<char const*>::value, void>::type std::__1::__fs::filesystem::_PathCVT<char>::__append_range[abi:v170000]<char const*>(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>&, char const*, char const*) /home/me/dev/llvm/build/bin/../include/c++/v1/__filesystem/path.h:316:12
    #3 0x563a8274cfcd in void std::__1::__fs::filesystem::_PathCVT<char>::__append_source[abi:v170000]<std::__1::basic_string_view<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>>(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>&, std::__1::basic_string_view<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>> const&) /home/me/dev/llvm/build/bin/../include/c++/v1/__filesystem/path.h:331:5
    #4 0x563a8274cb2e in std::__1::__fs::filesystem::path::path[abi:v170000]<std::__1::basic_string_view<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>, void>(std::__1::basic_string_view<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>> const&, std::__1::__fs::filesystem::path::format) /home/me/dev/llvm/build/bin/../include/c++/v1/__filesystem/path.h:483:5
    #5 0x563a82676438 in __cxx_global_var_init /home/me/dev/tmp/repro-asan.cpp:6:29
    #6 0x563a82676474 in _GLOBAL__sub_I_repro_asan.cpp /home/me/dev/tmp/repro-asan.cpp
    #7 0x7fca55896eba in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x29eba) (BuildId: 69389d485a9793dbe873f0ea2c93e02efaa9aa3d)
    #8 0x563a826764a4 in _start (/home/me/dev/tmp/repro-asan+0x1f4a4)

0x563a8315eb41 is located 1 bytes inside of global variable 'path' defined in '/home/me/dev/tmp/repro-asan.cpp:6' (0x563a8315eb40) of size 24
0x563a82764600 is located 32 bytes before global variable '.str.2' defined in '/home/me/dev/llvm/build/bin/../include/c++/v1/string:1984' (0x563a82764620) of size 13
  '.str.2' is ascii string 'basic_string'
0x563a82764600 is located 0 bytes inside of global variable '.str.1' defined in '/home/me/dev/tmp/repro-asan.cpp:4' (0x563a82764600) of size 5
  '.str.1' is ascii string '/usr'
SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: invalid-pointer-pair /home/me/dev/llvm/build/bin/../include/c++/v1/string:1979:23 in bool std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>::__addr_in_range[abi:v170000]<char const&>(char const&) const
==3183863==ABORTING
```

Looking at the source code of the library, there's indeed a comparison between two pointers: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/7f12efa88e17548d98f3e7425687f4afe0df34ed/libcxx/include/string#L1979

My understanding is that these pointers belong to different objects, meaning their comparison is undefined in C++. Thus, I'm wondering whether it's me doing something wrong (using the standard library wrong), or is it a problem with the library itself?

System: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Comment: An obvious bug, report it.

Comment: Thanks @HolyBlackCat , I just followed your suggestion: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/60526 .

Answer (score 2):

The problematic function is testing whether an element lies in a range with the following (from https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/main/libcxx/include/string#L1979):

```
return data() <= __p && __p <= data() + size();
```

where `__p` is the pointer under consideration and `[data(), data()+size())` the range.

> My understanding is that these pointers belong to different objects, meaning their comparison is undefined in C++.

It is not *undefined*, just *unspecified*. The comparison doesn't have to be consistent, but the operation must result in `true` or `false` and the rest of the execution must be consistent with either.

While the standard only says that the comparison is *unspecified*, on common architectures, such as libc++ is targeting, it is guaranteed that memory has a linear layout and that the comparison of addresses forms a total order, so that the check is actually fine (except in constant evaluation, where it is forbidden, which is why the linked function has a specific branch for that). In principle compilers could also arbitrarily choose the result of these operations e.g. for optimization purposes, but no compiler I am aware of does that. And libc++ may rely on such guarantees, even if they are not made explicitly.

What ASAN's `invalid-pointer-pair` is checking here is *not* a check for undefined behavior. It only checks for *unspecified* behavior which is very likely unintentional, and at least non-portable. In this case it seems to me that the use is however intentional, with the assumption that `<` forms a strict total order over pointer addresses on the given compiler/architecture.

Libc++ could have used `std::less` instead of the relational operators directly. `std::less` is specified to actually guarantee a total order of all pointer addresses. However, the standard library also has to make the same assumptions to implement `std::less` anyway and on a usual platform it will simply be implemented with the `<` operator itself, so I don't think this is a big improvement and I don't know whether ASAN would recognize that the diagnostic must be suppressed in this case either.

In the end, I guess there is simply a suppression missing here somewhere.